# models not showing in django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

My models in my admin page are not sowing up. I checked to see if my user was a super user, checked if my directories were good, and checked if my code was written wrong. As far as I know, all of these are correct. However I get this error when I add 'main.templates.admin.InfoAdmin' in settings.py.

```
...django\apps\registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready

raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Without that line there's no error, but the models don't show up on the admin page.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

class InfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [
    'site_title',
    'site_content',
    'site_published'
    ]

class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [
    'title',
    'description',
    'document',
    'uploaded_at',
    'creator'
    ]

admin.site.register(models.Info, InfoAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.Document, DocumentAdmin)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
class Info(models.Model):
    site_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    site_content = models.TextField()
    site_published = models.DateTimeField("date published")
    likes= models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes= models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.site_title

class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='NoTitle')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    creator = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from . import models

from django.conf.urls import url, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('$/', models.Info, name='Info'),
    path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path("myconta/", views.myconta, name="myconta"),
    path("upload/", views.model_form_upload, name="upload"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")), # <-- added
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
import sys, os, django

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.templates.apps.MainConfig',
    'main.templates.admin.InfoAdmin',
]
```

Comment: Try changing `admin.site.register(models.Info, InfoAdmin)` to `admin.site.register(Info, InfoAdmin)`

Comment: What is `path('$/', models.Info, name='Info')` supposed to do???? That's wrong, you should not import models in urls.py.

Comment: Check if every folder has __init__.py file in it.

Comment: And also `InfoAdmin` isn't an app, you shouldn't add that to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: I tried switching ```models.Info``` to ```Info``` and I just removed ```path('$/', models.Info, name='Info')``` and the ```from . import models```, but the same error still occurs

Comment: You shouldn't add `InfoAdmin` to your installed apps.

Comment: When I reomove ```'main.templates.admin.InfoAdmin'``` there's no error, but nothing appears on the admin page

Comment: Note if you use `from .models import *` you should specify your models as `Info` but if you use `from . import models` you should specify your models as `models.Info`. Also look at @dirkgroten comment on `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Why is everything in the `templates` directory anyway? If `main` is your app, then `admin.py`, `apps.py` etc... should just be in `main`. Didn't you use `manage.py startapp` to create your app? Look at the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/intro/tutorial01/#creating-the-polls-app) to see the folder structure for a Django project.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks, I did what you said and transferred my python files that were in the templates folder to my main folder and now it works!